# How to convert string to date formate in react native

Tags: reactjs, date, react-native, date-format

I am new to react native, I am getting date as string from server response.

start_date": "2016-05-12", But, I have to display in following format

```
May 12, 2016
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use moment.js to perform any date related operation. You can checkout more detail about the moment from [here](https://momentjs.com/).

Before converting any date which is in string, we need to convert into a date object. After that we can convert it into any formate.

```
let momentObj = moment('2016-05-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
let showDate = moment(momentObj).format('MMM DD, YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a moment.js library.

you can install it with `npm install --save moment`

**usage:**

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment('2016-05-12').format('MMM DD, YYYY');
```

Read more about moment here: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I think @nirmalsunh's answer is better as it converts the date string to a date before formatting. Your answer will not work in all scenarios.